# How to prevent deprecated folders being reintroduced as merge conflicts on every PR (git flow model)?

Tags: git

My team has a project where we have a `main` branch and a `develop` branch, and we branch off of `develop` to make new features (git flow essentially). Once we're satisfied with the state of `develop` (which is also used as the source of our staging environment), we make a PR to merge `develop` into `main`. However every time we merge `develop` into `main`, we get tons of merge conflicts, many involving files that no longer exist in either `main` or `develop` (this is the most confusing part).

Originally there was only a `master` branch that contained both a backend folder and frontend folder, but a while back we switched to the git flow model of `main`/`develop` (branched `develop` off of `master` and then `main` off of `develop`, this might be the cause of the issues) and also separated the backend out into a separate repo. As mentioned earlier, the current state of both main and develop has no frontend/backend folders; the repo root is the contents of the frontend folder (it's a React project so it has a src folder, package.json, etc.). Yet every PR into `main` reintroduces those original folders and it's a pain to keep dealing with these merge conflicts.

What would be the best way to fix this? Should we sync `develop` and `main` one last time and then delete `develop` and re-create it as a branch off of `main`? Or the other way around? Or some other solution?

Comment: Technically, [git rerere](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) should do the trick. But when you merge `develop` into `master`, don't you then merge `master` back into `develop`?

Comment: Not currently, right now feature branches merge into `develop`, and then after some features/testing in staging we merge `develop` into `main` like a release, so `develop` is typically ahead of `main` by design.

Comment: You  might want to try and merge `master` into `develop` after each release (some forms of gitflow would tell you to merge the `release` branch once into master and once into `develop`, but it's all the same). That way if master gets a change (either a hotfix or something else that is out of the ordinary) `develop` would know about it and upon future releases there won't be conflicts.